# Wget - output directory prefix

Tags: linux, bash, wget

Currently I try to use:

```
"wget --user=xxx --password=xxx -r ftp://www.domain.com/htdocs/"
```

But this saves output files to current directory in this fashion:

```
curdir/www.domain.com/htdocs/*
```

I need it to be:

```
curdir/*
```

Is there a way to do this, I only see a way to use output prefix, but i think this will just allow me to define directory outside current dir?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can combine `--no-directories` if you want all your files inside one directory or `--no-host-directories` to have subdirectories but no subdirectories per host with your `--directory-prefix` option.

> 2.6 Directory Options
>
> ‘-nd’
>   ‘--no-directories’
>      Do not create a hierarchy of directories when retrieving recursively. With this option turned on, all files will get saved to the current directory, without clobbering (if a name shows up more than once, the filenames will get extensions ‘.n’).
>
> ‘-nH’
>   ‘--no-host-directories’
>       Disable generation of host-prefixed directories. By default, invoking Wget with ‘-r http://fly.srk.fer.hr/’ will create a structure of directories beginning with fly.srk.fer.hr/. This option disables such behavior.
>
> ‘-P prefix’
>   ‘--directory-prefix=prefix’
>       Set directory prefix to prefix. The directory prefix is the directory where all other files and subdirectories will be saved to, i.e. the top of the retrieval tree. The default is ‘.’ (the current directory). 
>   (From the [wget manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html).)